# Which wallets belong to Satoshi Nakamoto?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto

I am curious to know which wallets belong to Satoshi Nakamoto? I heard that the BTC in them were never moved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No real way to tell that Satoshi indeed owns wallets (unless he sends a signed message).
You can assume which blocks he mined and therefore his wallets like so.
http://bitslog.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/the-well-deserved-fortune-of-satoshi-nakamoto/

Comment: it says 1148800 btc has not been spent. which address is this? most likely this is satoshi's?

Comment: You need to check each individual block, he used different addresses. For example, this is block #2: https://blockchain.info/block/000000006a625f06636b8bb6ac7b960a8d03705d1ace08b1a19da3fdcc99ddbd Note the transaction at the bottom of 50 btc. The receiving address of the btc appears to not have been touched until 2012 when some people sent it some small amount with public messages.

Comment: To check coins from first fifty blocks you can try this link https://goo.gl/bVdgtr