# Have the early mined coins been moved/transacted?

Tags: history, satoshi-nakamoto

Has anyone done an analysis of the early coins mined by Satoshi and Hal Finney? Have those coins been moved/spent/transacted?

I wonder whether Satoshi has been cashing in on his collection or does he just let it sit there?

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20565/which-wallets-belong-to-satoshi-nakamoto

Answer (score 1):

The earlist blocks have not been spent (except for block 9). You can be alerted by email when new transactions occur here http://bitcoinwhoswho.com/address/12cbQLTFMXRnSzktFkuoG3eHoMeFtpTu3S/

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the movement of coins on blockexplorers. Usually beside an output there is a spent/unspent designation.
If you look at block #10 for example
https://blockchain.info/block/000000002c05cc2e78923c34df87fd108b22221ac6076c18f3ade378a4d915e9
you see that the output (addr: 15yN7NPEpu82sHhB6TzCW5z5aXoamiKeGy) remains unspent.
You can look through other blocks in the same manner.