# How did we know that Satoshi Nakamoto has one million bitcoin?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto

As I know there is no known bitcoin wallet belongs to Satoshi Nakamoto. So how did we know that Satoshi Nakamoto owns between 750000 and 1100000 bitcoin?

Comment: who do you think mined the first blocks?

Comment: We don't. It's basically an urban legend motivated by the blog post linked here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/20569/5406

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which wallets belong to Satoshi Nakamoto?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20565/which-wallets-belong-to-satoshi-nakamoto)